# Android/Kotlin - LAGGY Checking item in BottomNavigationView from ViewPager

Tags: android, performance, kotlin, android-viewpager, android-navigation-bar

I am fairly new to programming, and this is my first large/real project.

**--Background--**

I have a ViewPager set up within my MainActivity, that slides between 3 different fragments. In Addition, one fragment requires menu items within the toolbar, and a BottomNavigationView is held within the MainActivity.

Each time i move to a new item/page of the ViewPager, i want to select(check) the corresponding page item within the BottomNavView.

I have attempted multiple configurations of the one below, but can't get it perfect

**--The Problem--**

The time it takes to perform **bottom_navigation.menu.getItem(pos).isChecked = true** is too long... Approx 50ms on my HTC One, or 100ms in the emulator.
This delay causes the ViewPager scrolling action to be jarred/laggy.

I would like to know if there is a different way to *check* or highlight the corresponding item within the BottomNavBar, or more desirably, perform the checking action at the same time without impeding the scrolling animation of the ViewPager.

**--Attempted Fixes--**

- Perform check within *onPageSelected* - (Result is slightly more laggy)
- Perform check when scroll state is *IDLE* - (Results in smooth pager scroll, but the checked item is 'left behind' and updated too late, particularly when scrolling fast)
- Find the navigation item in Anko's *doAsync{ }* - (Results don't change)

  ```
      // Adds a page-change listener
  viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(object : ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener {

      // Set Toolbar title and menu items
      override fun onPageSelected(position: Int) {
          when (position) {
              0 -> {
                  supportActionBar!!.title = "Page1"
                  toolbar.menu.setGroupVisible(0, false)
              }
              1 -> {
                  supportActionBar!!.title = "Page2"
                  if (toolbar.menu.size() == 0) {
                      toolbar.inflateMenu(R.menu.toolbar_list_menu)
                  } else {
                      toolbar.menu.setGroupVisible(0, true)
                  }
              }
              2 -> {
                  supportActionBar!!.title = "Page3"
                  toolbar.menu.setGroupVisible(0, false)
              }
          }
      }

      // While view pager settling on new item/page, check the correct bottom navigation view item
      override fun onPageScrollStateChanged(state: Int) {
          if (state == ViewPager.SCROLL_STATE_SETTLING) {
              val pos = viewPager.currentItem
              bottom_navigation.menu.getItem(pos).isChecked = true
          }
      }

      // Not needed, must be implemented
      override fun onPageScrolled(position: Int, positionOffset: Float, positionOffsetPixels: Int) {}
  })
  ```

I really hope someone has an answer to help with my apps performance :)

Thanks for your time.